# Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always authenticated?

Tags: asp.net, iis, forms-authentication

I am trying to create a httphandler which will intercept a sample pdf file which we have in our website.  The httphandler works fine from within my development machine and even my locally published website that if I just try to connect to the test url:
https://test.com/admin/_/sample_reports/sample.pdf I will get sent to the invalid access page.

So pushing it to our IIS6 machine when I try to go to the URL it serves up the PDF document.  context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always showing as true.

I'm using forms authentication.  below is the code I am using as the handler.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string SampleURL = context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;

        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.Clear();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(SampleURL),FileMode.Open))
        {
            int length = (int)fs.Length;
            byte[] buffer;

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                buffer = br.ReadBytes(length);
            }

            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Redirect(
           "~/Error/invalid_access.aspx");
    }}
```

in web.config I have the following for form authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="Sample.Web" loginUrl="~/Security/" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain="">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that

> So pushing it to our IIS6 machine when I try to go to the URL it serves up the PDF document. **context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always showing as true.**

This .PDF request may have already been processed by IIS 6 static file handler instead of your HTTP handler on IIS 6.

Comment: I'll check this but I don't believe it is

Answer (score 3):

`Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property is set to `true` when authentication cookie is still set and is still valid (not expired) for forms authentication.

> In the case of Forms authentication,
>   the forms authentication module uses
>   the encrypted authentication ticket
>   contained in the authentication cookie
>   to authenticate the user. Once it has
>   done this, it replaces the
>   `GenericIdentity` in
>   `Context.User.Identity` with a
>   `FormsIdentity` object that returns
>   `true` from its `IsAuthenticated`
>   property.

So, your auth cookie is still alive; it may be caused by calling one of those [`FormsAuthentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) methods like [`RedirectFromLoginPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx) or [`SetAuthCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) which are setting the auth cookie; or just by forgotten cookie.

Also it would be better to use [`HttpRequest.IsAuthenticated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated.aspx) instead of `Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` for your example. It checks whether `HttpContext.User` and `HttpContext.User.Identity` is not `null` and `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property is set to `true`. In your case when e.g. `HttpContext.User` is `null` your code will throw `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ProcessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx)

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
         context.Response.Redirect(
           "~/Error/invalid_access.aspx");
    }

}
```

**EDIT**: Might be IIS that is the culprit then,  do you have the following set? In IIS, anonymous access is ***enabled*** for all applications that use forms authentication

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: The ProcessRequest got chopped when I posted the code, corrected post.

Comment: see update to original post, but yes anonymous is enabled and deny users = "?"